# "-" replaced by "?" while importing csv to mysql

Tags: mysql, excel, csv

i have this data on xlsx file 
[image]
i saving it to csv file :
[image]
as you can see, every "-" character is replaced by "â€".
when i imported it to MySQL this is the result :
[image]

how can i importing data to database without replacing anything?

Comment: Doesn't seem like a lot of code here. Have you tried a CSV import into MySQL with `LOAD DATA INFILE`?

Comment: no, how to do it?

Comment: I don't think it is a `-`  I think it is a unicode character that looks like a dash only slightly wider (Office loves to convert what you type into unicode)  Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#Similar_Unicode_characters

Comment: use storage Engine as `InnoDB` and try to import the csv